# Kendo UI grid - How can I show a processing / loading percent indicator

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is there any way to show the processing percentage or a progress bar to show the loading progress to the user in Kendo grid. Kindly share.
-Philip-

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `dataBinding` and the `dataBound` event of the kendo.ui.Grid. Pseudo code

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataBinding: function(e) {
        //show your processing modaL
        console.log("dataBinding");
    },
    dataBound: function(e) {
        //hide your processing modaL
        console.log("dataBound");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks much for you reply.

Comment: When the data get fetch from the db (Creating json file)  using

Comment: When the data get fetch from the db (Creating json file) using 

read:  {
        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "get_cust_new.html",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback"
        },

Default processing icon appearing (ripple wave like) 
till data populate in the grid.
However user needs a customized processing graphics
(Progress bar ...) to show the progress percentage in the
json preparation at server side( url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "get_cust_new.html").
So that he will get an idea when he can see the data in the grid.
Is it possible ?

-Philip-